# Create the html files or insert the content from a database dynamically?

Tags: php, html, sql

Imagine we have a page with a form where users can create their own discussion forum by inserting some data. Inside each forum anyone will be able to post different threads and topics.

**Scenario 1:**

Use PHP to create a new HTML file every time a user creates his own forum. This would lead to hundreds maybe thousands of different html files.

**Scenario 2:**

We only have one html file in which contents change depending on the ID received (so it will display the contents for "discussion1", "discussion2" or any other discussion depending on the variable ID). This would mean having just one HTML file but a huge table in our SQL server.

I have seen examples of both scenarios for very large websites. For example, Wikipedia uses Scenario 1 while I believe other more dynamic websites use Scenario 2. **What are the main pros & cons of each scenario?**

I would love to know the pros & cons that matter most and also the ones related with:
- SEO
- Server response time & server load
- Site maintenance
- User experience (for bookmarks assume the ID is sent via the GET method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scenario 2 is certainly the way to go, keeping pages dynamic allows for editing far less files and means everything will always be the same.

With good MySQL tables and relationships the queries to the database shouldn't be that server heavy and your site will still perform a lot better than with hundreds of .html files.

I don't think many, if any sites use scenario 1, they will just .htaccess to alter the url and make them look like .html pages.

Answer (score 1):

I actually believe Wikipedia uses a database as well.  They are just parsing the URL to get the variables instead of using a query string in the URL.  And I would have to believe the database would be the way to go.  It's still going to be smaller because you'll have a lot less code. If you use HTML, you will be reproducing a lot of code that you just don't need to reproduce.

SEO-wise, as long as you do something like Wikipedia does and parse your URL with maybe an .htaccess file, google will be none-the-wiser.  It just doesn't really matter if your content is hard coded or not as long as you set it up right.

Answer (score 1):

The best case scenario would be a combination of the two, in this manner:

Use one template (scenario 2) to generate these pages on the fly, this way you can have millions of forums, with only one html.
With this, you should add a caching feature, which caches (creates a temporary html file) all the forums, so that users will not need to access the database every single page visit, but rather get the cached HTML from the server.